# How to redirect to user to container webapp but show different address

Tags: python, docker, flask, containers

I am creating a web application that when someone access it like that:

```
http://x.x.x.x:1337/bazinga
```

It will create a container with host's port `8083` maps to the container's port `80`. Then I want to redirect the user to the web application (`nginx`) inside the container.

To do that I need to redirect the user to `http://localhost:8083`, which will redirect to the container `nginx`. The problem is that I don't want the user to see the port `8083`. Because in the near future this web application should will 500 people and for each one I will create a container with different port, not only `8083` and I don't want them to be able to access someone else container by just trying different ports.

Therefore, I wanted to redirect the user to `http://localhost:8083` but without showing it. The user should see some random URL, i.e: `http://x.x.x.x/CS7YJVS7E8KTBD0AMDO3`.

How can I do that?

This is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask, session, redirect
import docker
import random
import string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Congratulations, it's a web app!"

@app.route("/<random_id>")
def random_url(random_id):
    if random_id not in global_routes:
        return "URL doesn't exist"

    return "My user!"

@app.route("/bazinga")
def bazinga():
    randomString = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(20))
    session["user"] = randomString

    container = client.containers.run("nginx", remove=True, detach=True, ports={'80/tcp':'8083/tcp'})
    global_routes[randomString] = True
    return redirect("http://localhost:8083")


global_routes = {}
client = docker.from_env()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=1337, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to do it.

I created a dynamic route like that:

```py
@app.route("/<random_id>")
def random_url(random_id):
    if random_id not in global_containers:
        return "URL doesn't exist"

    r = requests.get("http://localhost:" + str(global_containers[random_id].host_port))
    return r.content
```

I am saving the containers and redirect to the container's id.
Inside the route function, I can use the ID to find the container and send get request to the container return it back.